# Windows Phone App crashing without exceptions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I got a Windows Phone 8 app, that I've been developing over 2 years, its about 15k lines of code now. Starting from today it suddenly keeps crashing after showing the main screen for 5 secs. I've debugged it from the very first line of code and all the way through, to where the main screen is done running code.

I get no exceptions and I can't see anything wrong by the looks of it. Is there something else I can do to locate where/when/why it crashes?

EDIT: After a closer look i found this in my output:

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>   An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\System.Xml.debug.resources.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
>   An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{6932AD96-A8AA-45F2-BC4E-81B7665641D8}\Install\microsoft.phone.controls.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\LocationService.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
>   An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Unknown Module. and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>   The program '[2540] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

But I don't know what to make of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try handling the [`Application.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.application.unhandledexception%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event. This event is raised whenever an exception is unhandled by the Windows Phone application.

There may be certain very rare scenarios where this is not triggered though, like in the event of an OutOfMemoryException.

In your project, you should have a class that extends `Application`. Modify its constructor to subscribe to this event

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        ...
        this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, 
        ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: so i just place it somewhere in my code? and it will trigger by itself?

Comment: @user2408952 not quite. I've updated my answer showing how to subscribe to the `UnhandledException` event.

Comment: No, but looking closely in the output i noticed this(see updated question)

Comment: @user2408952 take an even closer look at the exception: you'll notice there's an `OutOfMemoryException`. And as I said in my answer, there is no way to catch an `OutOfMemoryException`, it's a catastrophic failure, and there wouldn't be an easy way to recover from it anyway. This means that you're either loading too much stuff into memory, or you have a memory leak because you're not disposing of your resources, or you're trying to allocate a huge chunk of memory at once. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah yes thx, my hope is that by fixing the System.Net.WebException it would also fix the outofmemory.

Comment: @user2408952 It should. Are you perhaps downloading images or something? Take a closer look at what's happening, it shouldn't be hard to find the leak.

Comment: I'm calling A LOT^^ of webcalls because its a 100% online app. Which also means the error is going to be a bit hard to locate:(. But now that i know whats wrong it should help quite a bit. Thanks a lot.

Comment: hmm as it turns out it is the OutOfMemoryException that's my main problem. i got a list containing my rss feeds when the list gets above 4-6. The number of feeds i can load before it crashes seems to be random, i guess it depends on how much memory each fed takes.